# Mapping over a vector performing side-effects

Tags: clojure

I am attempting to iterate over a vector of "lines" in Clojure.  Essentially, it looks like:

```
[{:start {:x 1 :y 3 :z 4}, :end {:x 3 :y 7 :z 0}}, ...]
```

I would like to apply a function that prints each of these "lines" onto a new line, ala:

```
(map #(println %) vector-of-lines)
```

but that doesn't appear to call the function.  Should I not be using the "map" function in this instance?

Comment: The hashmap bit is a red herring, and so I removed it from the title.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
(dorun (map println vector-of-lines))
```

`dorun` forces the evaluation of the lazy sequence, but also discards the individual results of each of item in the sequence. This is perfect for sequences that are purely for side-effects which is exactly what you want here.

Comment: The problem is it's not printing any lines.  I just included one example in the vector but it's actually of size 10.  However, using apply still results in no call being made to the anonymous function.

Comment: The println output should be going to the console wherever that may be in your environment.

Comment: The problem was not including dorun as you've mentioned.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

`map` is lazy and won't realize results unless you ask for them. If you want to perform a side effect for each element in a sequence, and don't care about the return value, use `doseq`:

```
;; returns nil, prints each line
(doseq [line vector-of-lines]
  (println line))
```

If you do care about the return value, use `(doall)`:

```
;; returns a sequence of nils, prints each line
(doall (map println vector-of-lines))
```

Comment: +1 on not wrapping println in a function since it is already a function.

Comment: The println was just an example. :D

Answer (score 4):

To add to Justin's answer, `doseq` is a macro, and thus carries with it all the limitations of macros.

I would write a `foreach` function that internally uses `doseq`.

```
user=> (defn foreach [f xs] (doseq [x xs] (f x)))
#'user/foreach

user=> (foreach println [11 690 3 45])
11
690
3
45
nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Clojure 1.7 there is `run!` which does what you want. The naming of this method may be related to the workaround with `dorun` and `map`. Be careful with using `map` for such occasions. Suppose that you make another call to `map` inside your function that you passed in. That will require walking the sequence as well. Thus, you will need to use `dorun` twice.