# How do I make this macro variadic in clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure

I want to make something called ds so that

```
(let [a 2]
  (ds a))
```

->

```
 "a->2"
```

and

```
(let [a 1 b 2 c 3]
    (ds a b c))
```

->

```
 "a->1, b->2, c->3"
```

And so far I've got as far as:

```
(defmacro ds3 [a b c] 
     `(clojure.string/join ", " 
          [(str '~a "->" ~a) 
           (str '~b "->" ~b) 
           (str '~c "->" ~c)]))
```

Which seems to work:

```
 (let [ a 1 b 2 c 3]
     (ds3 a b c)) ; "1->1, 2->2, 3->3"
```

Obviously I can define ds1 ds2 ds3 etc..., but I wondered how to make it variadic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(defmacro ds [& symbols]                                                                                                                             
  `(clojure.string/join ", "                                                                                                                         
                        ~(into [] 
                           (map (fn [s] `(str ~(name s) "->" ~s))  symbols))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Ankur's answer is probably the most practical, but he is deferring a lot of the work to runtime which could be done at macroexpansion time. It's a useful exercise, and a nice demonstration of the power macros can bring, to see how much of the work you can do at compile time:

```
(defmacro ds [& args]
  `(str ~(str (name (first args)) "->")
        ~(first args)
        ~@(for [arg (rest args)
                clause [(str ", " (name arg) "->") arg]]
            clause)))

(macroexpand-1 '(ds a b c))
=> (clojure.core/str "a->" a ", b->" b ", c->" c)
```

This avoids building any temporary objects at runtime, and does the absolute minimum number of string concatenations.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Thanks to suggestions by @amalloy, here are some improved macros that don't use the 'badly wrong' `eval` and include some mini-tests:

```
(import 'java.lang.ArithmeticException)

(defmacro explain-expr
  "Produce a string representation of the unevaluated expression x, concatenated to
  an arrow and a string representation of the result of evaluating x, including
  Exceptions should they arise."
  [x]
  `(str ~(str x) " ~~> "
        (try ~x (catch Exception e# (str e#)))))

(println (explain-expr (* 42 42)))
(println (explain-expr (let [x 1] x)))
(println (explain-expr (/ 6 0)))
(println (let [x 1] (explain-expr x)))
(let [y 37] (println (explain-expr (let [x 19] (* x y)))))
(let [y 37] (println (explain-expr (let [y 19] (* y y)))))
```

> ```
> (* 42 42) ~~> 1764
> (let [x 1] x) ~~> 1
> (/ 6 0) ~~> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero
> x ~~> 1
> (let [x 19] (* x y)) ~~> 703
> (let [y 19] (* y y)) ~~> 361
> ```

```
(defmacro explain-exprs
  "Produce string representations of the unevaluated expressions xs, concatenated
  to arrows and string representations of the results of evaluating each
  expression, including Exceptions should they arise."
  [& xs]
  (into [] (map (fn [x]
                  `(str ~(str x) " ~~> "
                        (try ~x (catch Exception e# (str e#)))))
                xs)))

(clojure.pprint/pprint
 (let [y 37]
   (explain-exprs
    (* 42 42)
    (let [x 19] (* x y))
    (let [y 19] (* y y))
    (* y y)
    (/ 6 0))))
```

> ```
> ["(* 42 42) ~~> 1764"
>  "(let [x 19] (* x y)) ~~> 703"
>  "(let [y 19] (* y y)) ~~> 361"
>  "(* y y) ~~> 1369"
>  "(/ 6 0) ~~> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero"]
> ```

```
(defmacro explanation-map
  "Produce a hashmap from string representations of the unevaluated expressions
  exprs to the results of evaluating each expression in exprs, including
  Exceptions should they arise."
  [& exprs]
  (into {}
        (map (fn [expr]
               `[~(str expr)
                 (try ~expr (catch Exception e# (str e#)))])
             exprs)))

(clojure.pprint/pprint
 (let [y 37]
   (explanation-map
    (* 42 42)
    (let [x 19] (* x y))
    (let [y 19] (* y y))
    (* y y)
    (/ 6 0))))
```

> ```
> {"(* 42 42)" 1764,
>  "(let [x 19] (* x y))" 703,
>  "(let [y 19] (* y y))" 361,
>  "(* y y)" 1369,
>  "(/ 6 0)" "java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero"}
> ```

**DEPRECATED**:

I'm leaving this in as an illustration of what *not* to do.

Here's a variation that will work on any kind of expression (I think)

```
(defmacro dump-strings-and-values
  "Produces parallel vectors of printable dump strings and values. A dump string
  shows an expression, unevaluated, then a funny arrow, then the value of the
  expression."
  [& xs]
  `(apply map vector ;; transpose
          (for [x# '~xs
                v# [(try (eval x#) (catch Exception e# (str e#)))]]
            [(str x# " ~~> " v#) v#])))

(defmacro pdump
  "Print dump strings for one or more given expressions by side effect; return
  the value of the last actual argument."
  [& xs]
  `(let [[ss# vs#]
         (dump-strings-and-values ~@xs)]
     (clojure.pprint/pprint ss#)
     (last vs#))
```

Some samples:

> ```
> (pdump (* 6 7))
> ```

prints `["(* 6 7) ~~> 42"]` and returns `42`.

> ```
> (pdump (* 7 6) (/ 1 0) (into {} [[:a 1]]))
> ```

prints

```
["(* 7 6) ~~> 42"
 "(/ 1 0) ~~> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero"
 "(into {} [[:a 1]]) ~~> {:a 1}"]
```

and returns `{:a 1}`.

**EDIT**:

My attempt to get rid of the outer brackets in the printed output, namely

```
(defmacro vdump
  "Print dump strings for one or more given expressions by side effect; return
  the value of the last actual argument."
  [& xs]
  `(let [[ss# vs#]
         (dump-strings-and-values ~@xs)]
     (map clojure.pprint/pprint ss#)
     (last vs#)))
```

does *NOT* work, and I'm not sure why.  It doesn't print output, but the macro expansion looks good. Could be an nREPL or REPL issue, but I gave in and just use the one above and don't worry about the brackets much.

Comment: It doesn't work with a closure because you're using eval. eval does not have access to the lexical environment, so this cannot work. Happily, it is quite possible to do just what you're doing without the use of eval, in the manner described in the other answers. I leave to you the exercise of using the same technique as the other answers to provide the more general features you were aiming for. (I downvoted this because using `eval` for this is badly wrong; I would happily convert to an upvote if you did it at macro time instead).

Comment: Oh, reading your answer more carefully I see I misunderstood what you were saying doesn't work. What I first meant was that `(let [x 1] (vdump x))` won't work because of scoping, but you probably didn't try that. Rather, your code is failing to print because [map is lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10857690/625403).

Comment: @amalloy oh, yes, I forgot about the lazy map.

Comment: @amalloy i posted some better macros for your consideration.