# Side effect optimized out

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure and at some moment I faced with the problem.

I have such code in my program:

```
(let [ ... ]
    (map (fn [[v f]] (do-side-effect v f)) {:v1 f1, :v2 f2})
    (do-the-job ...))
```

This `do-side-effect` can be, for example, `println` of another side effect function like `intern`. The problem is that side effect doesn't happen.

But if i change the line to

```
(println (map #(fn [[v f]] (do-side-effect v f)) {:v1 f1, :v2 f2}))
```

Then everything is ok. 
So the last idea i came to is that clojure 
just optimize out the `map` because
it think that it's result is useless because I don't use it.

In case if this actually happens, how can I show clojure that this form
can have side effects to prevent compiler from optimizing it out?

In case if it's a bug, how can I find where the bug is?

Comment: I think this is well explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857690/mapping-over-a-vector-performing-side-effects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map` is lazy. It is not meant to be used directly for side effects, and it only produces values when they are consumed.

You can use `dorun` to force the values to be realized, even if you are not consuming them, or use `doseq` instead of map, `doseq` is intended to be used for side effects, and unlike map won't spend time constructing objects you won't ever access.

Comment: Thank you for such quick reply! I forgot about the laziness of map, so aswer is much simplier that I expected.