# Clojurescript map function behaving unexpectedly

Tags: printing, clojure, clojurescript, map-function

I have two code snippets that I assumed to both result in alerts. However the first results none while the second performs the alerts.

```
(map #(.alert js/window %) ["hey1" "hey2"])
```

This slight modification prints (nil nil) as expected, as well as fixing the alert issue. The question being **WHY**?

```
(print (map #(.alert js/window %) ["hey1" "hey2"]))
```

Another weird observation is that the first snippet works from a browser-repl, but not when typed into code.

Is the map function side effect free, but print is not? Maybe some core code optimization I do not know about?

Work-arounds and answers are both appreciated. If you need more info please let me know in a comment.

[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.8.51"]

BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.7.0

BOOT_VERSION=2.5.5

java version "1.8.0_101"

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side effect optimized out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097067/side-effect-optimized-out)

Comment: Yes they are both talking about the same topic. However the type of people who are wondering this question likely do not know what a side effect is or that it is what is causing their problem. Thus I think my question is more likely to be found by the people who need its answer. ***In summary the only reason for keeping this question here is that it does not contain the words side effect in the question*** If you don't think this is important, then it would be reasonable to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use `map` for a side-effecty operation like alert.  The issue you are seeing is a result of `map` being lazy, so it won't actually do the work until you consume the elements of the resulting sequence.  If you really want to do side-effect sort of things, `doseq` might be a better option, especially if you don't need a sequence of results:

```
(doseq [msg ["hey1" "hey2"]]
  (.alert js/window msg))
```

Or you can use `doall` to force the evaluation of the whole sequence:

```
(doall (map #(.alert js/window %) ["hey1" "hey2"]))
```